# Cleaning up strikeout/coloured data in Excel

Tags: r, excel

I'm processing data where the source is a manual update in Excel format which is provided monthly.

One of the quirk of the data is that some cancelled records are indicated either by the person keying in the data highlighting the cells in red, or changing the fonts to be strikeout. Unfortunately I have no control on the data entry source, so I have had to regularly manually search the file for red cells or strike out fonts, and manually clean them up (either delete, or add a column with status as Cancelled, depending on the usage).

Does anyone have suggestion on the best data cleaning practice for this? Is there an automated approach for this, or do I simply have to be resigned to documenting the steps, and executing them regularly?

For info my preferred tool is R, so if there is a way to clean it from within R, that would be best. I'm open to other approaches.

Comment: u might use awk scripts for row/column selections...

Comment: Off-topic. You might try asking on a Windows applications users forum. Excel is not Data Science (joke: What is Big Data? Anything too large to load into Excel)

Comment: @Spacedman: I may be confused: I was thinking Data Science handles all kind of data, BigData and not-so-big data. Unless this is a Big Data forum?

Also, I'm hoping to see if there's non-Excel-native solution (like R), but it seems there is none. I will leave it open for a while more in hope, before accepting an answer.

Comment: Then its a programming question and you ask on StackOVerflow. Either way its a simple programming question, I can't imagine this would be covered in, for example, a University course on Data Science.

Comment: The key is the "Science" part of the name. Your question is going to elicit purely technical solutions - whether it's about how to use Excel or how to use R.

Comment: There is no data science without programming. This is a question about data cleaning solutions used by practicing data scientists. Technical solutions for data wrangling problems is going to be a substantial part of what users are going to look in this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few R packages for working with Excel, but filtering data based on formatting is going to involve using rcom and excel's COM interface.  I'm not terribly familiar with either.

The route I would go is to write a VBA macro which would filter the data, wrap that macro in a VBS script, and call that script from the command line (or via R's `system` or `shell` functions)

The reason I would go that route is that both VBA and VBS are very easy to pick up if you have any familiarity at all with programming.  COM on the other hand isn't something that people gain a level of comfort with very quickly.

VBA is what will give you access to the excel formatting.  (Visual Basic for Applications).  VBS is what you will need to automate the macro via the command line rather than from within Excel (Visual Basic Scripting Edition).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Excel. Start by recording a macro, then put a colour based filter on the column you want (to select only the red cells), delete the rows and then stop recording of the macro.

This should give you a macro. You might need to make some small changes, you can google specific commands for more details.